# 3 as a sum of three integer cubes

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations

Until now, the only known integer solutions to the equation $x^{3}+y^{3}+z^{3}=3$ were $(x, y, z)=(1,1,1)$ and $(4, 4, -5)$ (up to their permuations). I have just seen on Facebook someone posting that

$$569936821221962380720^3
+ (-569936821113563493509)^3
+ (-472715493453327032)^3 = 3,$$ but didn't reveal the discoverer of the result. Also, i couldn't find any news of this on Google. Has anyone else heard of this yet ?

Comment: See *'Computational Results'* on this [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sums_of_three_cubes#Computational_results). The discoverers are Andrew Booker and Andrew Sutherland in September 2019 (this month).

Comment: This is even more spectacular than the solution of $a^3+b^3+c^3=42$ I recently read in our newspaper.

Comment: @peter that is also is in the WP article referenced by projectilemotion.

Comment: See the related Numberphile-video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zyG8Vlw5aAw